# Elasticsearch spatial queries (within particular radius)

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch for my application. In that I am trying to run spatial queries for a given lat,long but I couldn't get the result....

My index looks like this:

```
"hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "pca_beta_v1",
            "_type": "place",
            "_id": "8neiQuwqTMmCLPo7Yu6TxA",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "idmap70": 305215,
               "id_0": 356,
               "id_1": "33",
               "id_2": "602222",
               "id_3": "566693",
               "id_4": "628343548",
               "name_0": "India",
               "name_1": "aaaaa",
               "name_2": "bbbb",
               "name_3": "cccc",
               "name_4": "nnnnnn",
               "latitude": 13.534991,
               "longitude": 80.015182,
               "key": "ooooooo",
               "leveltype": "ttttt"
}}]
}
```

I tried the following query:

```
GET bdrtfd/_search/
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "filter": {
    "geo_distance": {
      "location": {
        "lat": "13.534991",
        "lon": "80.015182"
      },
      "distance": "3km"
    }
  }
}
```

But i am getting error:

```
{
   "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed; shardFailures {[pPP8DQK9QASt8h9RUKAmsQ][pca_beta_v1][0]: SearchParseException[[pca_beta_v1][0]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n  \"query\": {\n    \"match_all\": {}\n  },\n  \"filter\": {\n    \"geo_distance\": {\n      \"location\": {\n        \"lat\": \"13.534991\",\n        \"lon\": \"80.015182\"\n      },\n      \"distance\": \"3km\"\n    }\n  }\n}\n]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[pca_beta_v1] failed to find geo_point field [location]]; }]",
   "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `"latitude": 13.534991, "longitude": 80.015182` fields in your mapping need to have a different kind of type to be able to be used in geo location computations. It needs to be only one field, not two, and it must be like this:

```
    "location": {
      "type": "geo_point"
    }
```

And then, when indexing, you specify something like this:

`{"location":{"lat":13.534991,"lon":80.015182}}`

And then your query will work.